# android.view.ActionMode vs android.support.v7.view.ActionMode, which one should I use and what are the differences?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using 'AppCompact' and I was implementing 'ActionMode.Callback' and I saw 2 different 'ActionMode' with same override methods. The 'android.view.ActionMode' is doing what I wanted to do in my app, but i'm little bit confused which one should i use, what is the difference between them?

Comment: It's a support library version, check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/) link, look for the section **Uses for the Support Libraries**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support libraries provide newer API features for older SDK versions. If your minimum SDK version is less than Lollipop (Android 5.0, API 21) then you must use the support library version of ActionMode (`android.support.v7.view.ActionMode`), otherwise you can use normal library version (`android.view.ActionMode`).

Answer (score 0):

If your app minSdkVersion above Lollipop use just ActionMode , if else v7